# Disable activeX warning on excel open

Tags: excel, activexobject, vba

Now iam working in excel macro project.There i have used one activeX object in form.Whenever i open the excel file it showing popup saying activeX control might be unsafe.Attached the screen shot.I dont want this warning.Please help [Warning Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2qkI.png)

Comment: Look into this: Look into this: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Enable-or-disable-ActiveX-settings-in-Office-files-f1303e08-a3f8-41c5-a17e-b0b8898743ed

Answer (score 0):

This is a default warning, which is a good thing - You don't want ActiveX controls to be instantiated if you don't know the source. Same goes for Macro's in general, etc. etc.

Under `File` -> `Options` -> `Trust Center` you can play around with these settings and disable the warning. I would advise against it, though.

Keep in mind that this setting will have to be changed for each individual user that will use your Macro enabled workbook.

Comment: Under `Trust Center`, on the left select `ActiveX Settings`. Select the bullet for `Enable all controls without restrictions and without prompting`. That should be it.

Comment: Yes i done that still same.activex object is added in tha vba form.